# Node.js / express.js client and server in one app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I need to write a node.js web application, which shows us some data from our databases.

My first idea was, to make a RestFul-webservice and a webclient. But I see two problems: 
- I need one open port for the service and one for the client. And we have only one open port, which I can use. 
- You can see the service address and routes in the client.

So my second idea is, to write one node.js application which has backend and frontend inside.

But I have tottaly no idea, how to consume the data from the service, without showing the addresses and routes on the clientside.

Is there any option to write some backend functions and use them in the frontend part, so nobody can see what there is happaning? For the frontend I want to use bootstrap, chart.js and jquery.

Here an example to see what I mean. Or should I do something completely different?? I want the "Hello World!" from my route "/hello", to show in my index.html in for example between a ".

```
//My Server.js
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();
var path = __dirname + '/views/';
router.use(function (req, res, next) {
console.log("/" + req.method);
next();
});

router.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path + "index.html");
});

router.get("/about", function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path + "about.html");
});

router.get("/hello", function (req, res) {
    res.send('Hello World!'); 
});

app.use("/", router);

app.use("*", function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path + "404.html");
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log("Live at Port 3000");
});


//My Index.html
<body>
<div>
<div>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation" style="padding-
left:130px;">
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="active"><a href="/">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
</a></li>
  <li><a href="/about">About us</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="jumbotron"> <p>
This is place to put content. 
</p></div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Assuming you have jquery? What you want is to retrieve the content of a route? Without exposing the route's name (so in your example, without exposing "/hello")? You do not want to expose it in your javascript aswell? Or just not expose it in the URL's bar?

Comment: Both I don't want, or maybe I express myself bad. But I think I found a solution. The frameworks "meteor" and "mean" seem to do what I need.

Comment: you probably do not need something so heavy but if it meet your needs :)

Comment: Maybe you have an easier idea :) It is so: I got one Server, which is reachable from outsout over just one Port (for example 3000). Normally I would make a webservice with java and run it on port 3000 and make a Website which consumes from the webservice. But to run the website, I would need another port.

Comment: I can think of 3 solutions, depending on your needs: 1. Your java-app could return HTML. The most easy solution and it work well. I think for little project this is the thing to do (not many and easy business rules). 2. You have webservice, and your java-app returns on `/` URL an index.html. In your javascript you can code AJAX request to consume your webservice. I think this tactic is nice when what you want is a single page which can trigger click on button to consume webservice. Here the advantage is: You have a restAPI, so your business rules are well organized

Comment: 3. You can have webservice in your java-app and then an index.html is returned on `/`. Then you can have JS framework like VueJS or AngularJS working on your index.html. This is nice when you want webservice but having multiple routes displayed on the browser. It is the heaviest solution, many headache come from it : You must have a strong router (by example, you want all route return index.html and some route return your webservice, but you have to manage error-code like 404 from the server, so you must know what route you have in your frontend app). The learning curve to do it well is big

Comment: you must know : Javascript , a frontend framework, some tool (like webpack / npm). Debugging this kind of app is a headache aswell. The security on a frontend app is hard to obtain, most of people want to use npm's module, but you do not know what is inside and you have many many many module's choice.
But it is very nice to have a loose coupling between your front logic and your data/business logic.